# Per-pixel marching ants selection border in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I've found a few rectangular marching ants selection methods, mostly using a rectangle, such as this one on [CodeProject: Marching Ants Selection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27816/Marching-Ants-Selection). Using a shape and storyboard could be made to work. The problem there is I control the [image's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image(v=vs.110).aspx) zoom using a [grid's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid(v=vs.110).aspx) scale layout transform, which would also change the size of shape's border.

However, I'd like to be able to create *per-pixel* selection borders:

[image]

My current plan is to store a bitmap containing a bitmask representing the currently selected pixels, but I would then have to walk its perimeter using something like [Marching Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares) to build a composite [path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path(v=vs.110).aspx) that represents the border.

Still, maybe there's a better way?

Here is some some hypothetical XAML showing what I'm planning:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="PART_Workspace" Grid.Column="1" 
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

    <Grid x:Name="PART_Grid" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <!-- This controls the zoom -->
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="PART_ScaleTransform"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Grid.LayoutTransform>

        <Canvas x:Name="PART_SelectionLayer">

            <!-- THIS REGION TO BE GENERATED AT RUNTIME -->
            <Path Style="{StaticResource SelectionBorder}"
                  StrokeThickness="! Possibly multiply this by inverse of zoom? !">
                <Path.Data>
                    <PathGeometry> <!-- one border around a region --> </PathGeometry>
                    <!-- additional borders -->
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
            <!-- THIS REGION TO BE GENERATED RUNTIME -->

        </Canvas>

        <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
        <!-- This displays the bitmap, which is updated elsewhere by code -->
        <Image x:Name="PART_ImageCanvas" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Can you give a concise (xaml) example of what you are trying to add a selection border to?  (Or if you are working with a bitmap, are you dealing with a bitmask that represents the selected pixels?)

Comment: The bitmask represents the selected pixels.

Comment: That is, the selected pixels don't conform to any control. They represent pixels inside an image, determined by a completely separate data structure that isn't part of WPF. That's the current idea, anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are dealing with a bitmask representing selection, and want to get the one-pixel border that represents the outline of the selection, you can use a square morphological operator to do so.  Once you do, you mask a pattern, and overlay it to get an approximation of marching ants.

Start with the binary selection mask where 1 is selected and 0 is unselected:

[image: original][image: selection mask]

Dilate the mask using a 3px square kernel and subtract the original image from the dilated image:

[image: Image as dilated][image: Image showing only an outline]

Mask the outline with a checkerboard pattern to get marching ants:

[image: 2x2 checkerboard][image: mask for marching ants]

Overlay the mask on the original image to get the overall effect.  Shift the checkerboard to get a "chase" effect:

[image: chase around selection]

This can be done in a fairly simple tight loop, the only complicated part is the dilation, which you can get from AForge.net or OpenCV.  Per pixel, the loop ends up doing:

```
if (dialated & !selected) 
{
    if (checkerboard)
    {
        pixel = red;
    }
}
```

---

If you already have the outline path, and you want it to match an image that has been scaled, I would scale the outline to be in screen units.  That way, both `BorderThickness` and `UseLayoutRounding` will work as expected.